# VBA to run macro then loop through other sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying (and failing) to get some code to run on each worksheet except one specific sheet. I want the code to just cut the data in cells n2:s2 and paste it in t1:y1, then repeat for any other rows that have data in columns n3:s3, n4:s4, n5:s5.

Once there is no data (row 6 i believe), it should move onto the next sheet (except "Report" sheet).
The problem i'm facing when i debug is it moves the data as expected, then starts again on the same sheet, so overwrites data with empty cells.

```
Sub MovethroughWB()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'This statement starts the loop

        If ws.Name <> "Report" Then 'Perform the Excel action you wish (turn cell yellow below)

            Range("N2:S2").Select
            Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("T1:Y1")
            Range("T1:Y1").Select
            Range("N3:S3").Select
            Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("Z1:AE1")

        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

I'm sure its something basic, but can't find what!

Comment: after `if` use `With ws` and before `End if` use `End With` in other case Excel is doing everything in active sheet

Comment: wow - i think it worked - just testing it now - thanks Teamothy

Comment: And read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: I spoke too soon..not sure what is going on but its not working again :( My code is Sub MovethroughWB2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'This statement starts the loop
If ws.Name <> "Report" Then 'Perform the Excel action you wish (turn cell yellow below)
With ws
Range("N2:S2").Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("T1:Y1")
Range("T1:Y1").Select
Range("N3:S3").Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("Z1:AE1")
End With
End If
Next ws

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub MovethroughWB()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i  As Long, Lastrow As Long, Lastcolumn As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'This statement starts the loop
        If ws.Name <> "Report" Then 'Perform the Excel action you wish (turn cell yellow below)
            With ws
                Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
                For i = 2 To Lastrow
                    If .Range("N" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("O" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("P" & i).Value <> "" _
                        And .Range("Q" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("R" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("S" & i).Value <> "" Then
                        If .Range("T1").Value = "" Then
                            .Range("N" & i & ":S" & i).Cut .Range("T1:Y1")
                        Else
                            Lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                            .Range("N" & i & ":S" & i).Cut .Range(.Cells(1, Lastcolumn), .Cells(1, Lastcolumn + 5))
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i

                .Rows("2:" & Lastrow).EntireRow.Delete

            End With

        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code - it kind of worked....I need it to move the data i n2:s2 to t1:y1 and the data from n3:s3 to z1:ae1, so all data resides on row 1, and then i will delete rows 2&3 etc

Comment: How would it on the end to delete all but row 1 before it moves onto the next sheet?